# Set up attribution through tag manager, not sure if the syntax is right

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager, conversion-tracking

For a multiple domain site I have set up a way to measure if conversions come through AdWords or E-mail by creating a cookie of the UTM-Medium UTM Tag.

Now this worked nicely on my product pages which I created in seperate tag manager containers. But to save me some time I created a global tag manager container. I used the following the fill in the hidden field with the cookie:

```
<script>
 document.querySelector(".gfield .gform_hidden").value = "{{Cookie - utm_medium}}";
</script>
```

I used the DOM element variable with Regex is not null to only fire this tag on the contact page. Since the only unique class on the contact page is: .page-template-template-contact which is on the body I used a class with some large content.

Is the method I used correct? The number of contact conversions seemed to be very low yesterday and I got an error with one of the fields while filling it out on my phone. Desktop was fine though.

The page: https://www.unisgroup.de/kontakt/ note: I have temporarily paused the tags.

Comment: Just a look at the syntax and telling me if it's correct would be good too (I need to know if this can crash the forms)

Comment: I'm a little confused with this method, if configured correctly with adwords, source/medium should come through without you picking it up using GTM. Do you have adwords connected and links in your emails tagged with UTM? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Source/medium is a dimension in GA https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6099206?hl=en

Comment: The CRM the company I work at is very old and needs manual input to recognize if a request is from AdWords. So I actually have to send the text Adwords in the confirmation mail since this is the way we measure revenue..